# Converting Dataflex/PowerFlex Program for Windows

Tags: windows

I have an old program written in Dataflex/PowerFlex from back in the mid 90's and I would like to see if I can get it running on Windows. I have all of the raw code files, but I don't know if I'm missing a runtime, the program needs to be complied or what. I do know that I've seen this program run before, but it had to be fired up through a DOS prompt if that's a clue for anyone.

Does anyone have an idea of what I need to get started doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically had two batch files to compile and run the console-mode dataflex programs.

The first, say progcomp.bat would include this to compile the source:
dfcomp prog.src

Then prog.bat would include this to run the program: 
echo off 
cls 
flex prog 
echo on 
cls

also, [dataaccess.com](http://www.dataaccess.com) still has a pretty good knowledgebase

Hope this helps
Garry